# Matlab Use Regex Expression to load file from directory

Tags: regex, matlab, file, load

I have looked a lot for this but have not found anything. I am very new to matlab and regex in general.

My problem is,  have a directory path 'dir' with only one .txt file in it. I do however not know the filename of the txt file. I want to load this file.

I have tried multiple things but cannot find the solution.

```
foo = load(fullfile(dir, '-regexp', '*.txt'))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That syntax isn't valid for `fullfile`, and `dir` is an in-built function which it appears you're using as a variable... Here is something a little clearer which should work when you have a single `txt` file within a given `folder`

```
folder = 'my\folder\path\';
files = dir( fullfile( folder, '*.txt' ) );

if numel( files ) ~= 1
    error( 'More or less than one .txt file found!' );
end

filepath = fullfile( files(1).folder, files(1).name );

foo = load( filepath ); % load is designed for .mat files, if your .txt contains anything
% non-numeric then you may want something more like readtable here...
```